# woocommerce api key not generating

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i am trying to generate a key for woocommerce api, but for some reason i am not seeing anything generated. i don't get any errors from what i can see. just says that my "settings are saved" but no keys appear and no qr code is seen, as it shows in the docs. i made sure the enable api checkbox was checked. i've tried multiple times but always brings me back to the attached screenshot. i am working locally using flywheel, so my project is not live, not sure if that has to do with anything.

[image]

Comment: Disable all your plugins and try again, just to exclude plugin conflicts possibility.

Comment: that did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

so i tested woocommerce on another project i had and it worked fine. ended up readding the plug in on the project in question and it started working.